# Determining if each vector element exceeds all previous elements

Tags: r

I need to compare element `i` with all previous elements `i-1,i-2,...`, and if `i > i-1, i-2, ...` return 1, otherwise return 0.

```
data <- c(10.3,14.3,7.7,15.8,14.4,16.7,15.3,20.2,17.1,7.7,15.3,16.3,19.9,14.4,18.7,20.7)
```

The result of comparing should be the following.

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Apart from the first item, this is `as.integer(cummax(data)==data)`... thinking there's a dupe.

Comment: @akrun Based on the OP's description (`v[i] > v[i-1], v[i-2],...`), I guess the first value is arbitrary or a matter of convention, since for `i=1` the condition is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one standard way:

```
as.integer(cummax(data) == data)
```

The value of the first element is `1` here instead of the OP's preferred `0`, but that is easy to tweak.

Comment: Posting because I could not find a dupe.